# how use dll in another dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, embed

I am making a DLL that I have to use another DLL. For example in my DLL I want to use "Ionic.Zip" component to unzip files.
How can do it ?

I found some code to use a DLL from Resources but I don't know how use in my code:
this is the Function:

```
private System.Reflection.Assembly ResolveAssemblies(object sender, System.ResolveEventArgs e)
{
   dynamic desiredAssembly = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(e.Name);

        if (desiredAssembly.Name == "Ionic_Zip") 
        {
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.Ionic_Zip);
        } 
        else {return null; }

}
```

and on form_load:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssemblies;
```

But when i want use it, have error with Ionic_Zip.
For example in my WinForm App I have a function like below to unzip files that use Ionic_Zip component:

```
private void UnzipUpdtFile()
{
   // extract all files in an existing zip that uses encryption
        using (var zip = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(UpdFilePCAdrss + @"\" + spl[spl.Length - 1]))
        {
            zip.Password = ZipPassword;
            zip.ExtractAll(UpdFilePCAdrss);
        }
}
```

How can use it at this function?

Comment: I assumed this was C#.

Comment: You can't simply add a reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx?

Comment: Why are you putting it in as a resource? Seems pointless, but anyway, what you are looking for is the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event

Comment: If you really need to keep it in resources (why not reference), you would pull binary from there, save it to a file, do `Assembly.LoadFromFile` and then use bunch of invokers of your members. But you will need to know all the names of the methods.

Comment: I want to build a **single dll file**  and not important the store place of dll (reference or resources ) .

Comment: Why do you want to embed one DLL inside another?  What is the actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: **I am creating a dll that i have to use a component Ionic to unzip and and I want to build single dll because its better. **